# Why doesn't Ubuntu Touch support multiple users?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Why can't Ubuntu mobile os support multiple users just like the desktop edition, capability of creating multiple user accounts. What is it that Ubuntu desktop OS support multiple accounts and not in Ubuntu mobile OS? I know the one is meant for a mobile devices and the other desktop pc? So in general whats the difference between two? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the reason multiple users is not available in Ubuntu Touch is that it is an operating system mainly for phones and tablets and those are usually just used by one person.  Ubuntu Desktop does support multiple accounts because sometimes families just own computer and all the people in the family use just that one with separate accounts  But I see your point.  It would be good to have multiple users, especially on tablets.

Comment: Eh, I don't think that's a valid answer. Android and Windows both support multiple accounts on tablets.